# PGFPlots: PNG has wrong rotation in .tex after matlab2tikz export

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, rotating, png, matlab2tikz

I got a problem, which I am somehow not able to solve for days.
I created a graph in Matlab and wanted to import it in my LaTeX document. This is my MATLAB Code.

```
figure();
subplot(2,1,1);
L_input = L_input ./ L_D;
x_axis = repmat(t.',1,numel(L_input));
y_axis = repmat(L_input, numel(t), 1);
z_axis = ergebnis;
plot = plot3(x_axis,y_axis,z_axis, 'k');
view(45,45);
xlim([-10 10]);
ylim([0 L_input(end)]);
xlabel('Verzögerung t');
ylabel('Distanz z/L_D');
zlabel('Intensität A');
grid;

% second Image
subplot(2,1,2);
imagesc(t,L_input,abs(ergebnis));
imgzposition = 10;
%surf([min(min(t)) max(max(t))],[min(min(L_input)) max(max(L_input))],repmat(imgzposition, [2 2]),...
%    abs(ergebnis),'facecolor','texture')
%s = surf(t,L_input,ergebnis);
%set(s, 'edgecolor','none')
view(45,45);
xlim([-10 10]);
ylim([0 L_input(end)]);
colormap hot; 
set(gca,'YDir','normal');
cleanfigure('minimumPointsDistance', 10);
matlab2tikz('./LaTeX/final_dispersion.tex', 'floatFormat', '%.2f', ...
        'height', '\figureheight', 'width', '\figurewidth');
```

[image: MATLAB Figure]

But somehow the PGFPlots interpreter is not able to rotate and scale the PNG parts of that graph properly. I used `view(45,45)` in Matlab for the perspective. As you can see, I tried `imagesc()` and `surf()` for creating the colormap. But both functions give the same output in LaTeX. Without rotation PGFPlots returns the right 2D picture. In LaTeX I used the following simple Code for the Import:

```
 \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \newlength\figureheight
    \newlength\figurewidth
    \setlength\figureheight{0.3\textwidth}
    \setlength\figurewidth{0.8\textwidth}
    \inputencoding{cp1252}
    \input{./final_dispersion.tex}
    \label{fig:Dispersion}
    \inputencoding{latin1}
\end{figure}
```

But with perspective rotation I got the following result:

[image]

Is that an PGFPlots bug, or is it my fault? Someone had an related issue? 
Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. The current version of PGFPlots is 1.14. Could you first update to the new version and then retry?

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't help. It creates the same output

Comment: Then please edit your question and provide your code and the picture, so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. Pgfplots uses the image as the plot and puts axes around them. It doesn't do any transformation to the image itself. Just sees an image. You might want to export the data to a file and plot it directly within pgfplots maybe ?

Comment: Is it realy like this? would be very bad or? Its hard to believe, because some transformation seem to be possible, otherwise setting the limits for png-graphs in latex wouldn't work anymore, right? And the picture above shows that the png is also cropped to fit inside the axis. But rotation is not possible?

Comment: Look at the pgfplots manual for `\addplot[...] graphics {...}` option.

Comment: BTW, why do the numbers on the Distanz z/L_D axis not match?